# Webhost/webpage - is it possible to keylog users PC or Opened Tab

Tags: javascript, html, xss, keylogger, websecurity

Say that I am a website developer/host; and someone comes to my page (eg: “my page.com”) and opens a link in my page to another site (eg: “test.com”). This opens in a new tab.

Is there a way for my page to keylog the user as they interact with the other page (or just Keylog their pc for x agreed duration)? (After accepting pop up that says by opening this link you agree to having keystrokes/mouse tracked)

I’m thinking it’s not possible because it’s potentially dangerous (does this fall under cross site scripting?) but my interest case is similar to selenium (browser recording extension), but without the need for an extension. I’m interested in the security around this and better ways to record user interaction with an external page (cookies??). I’m quite new to all this

Comment: not likely, if the browser opens another website, your website is no longer active, and your keylogging Javascript is not running anymore.

Comment: That makes sense thought it was probably the case, the more I read the more naive I feel!